# Oracle SQL SUBSTR function

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I have a table like below:

```
Last_name First_name
aaaa       bbb -
aaa        bbbb -
aaa        gggg j
```

How can I use substr function to delete the - in the `first_name` and keep the letter if it is not a -?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [rtrim()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions141.htm) function, specifying as a second parameter character(s) that you want to remove from the right-hand side of a string:

```
SQL> with t1(Last_name, First_name) as(
  2    select 'aaaa',  'bbb -' from dual union all
  3    select 'aaa',   'bbbb -' from dual union all
  4    select 'aaa',   'gggg j' from dual
  5  )
  6  select last_name
  7       , rtrim(first_name, ' -') as first_name
  8    from t1
  9  ;
```

Result:

```
LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME
--------- ----------
aaaa      bbb
aaa       bbbb
aaa       gggg j
```

Starting from Oracle 10g version, you could also use [regexp_replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) regular expression function:

```
select last_name
     , regexp_replace(first_name, '\s*-\s*$') as first_name
  from t1
```

Result:

```
LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME
--------- ----------
aaaa      bbb
aaa       bbbb
aaa       gggg j
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use SUBSTR, try this:

```
with t1(Last_name, First_name) as(
  select 'aaaa',  'bbb -' from dual union all
  select 'aaa',   'bbbb -' from dual union all
  select 'aaa',   'gggg j' from dual
)
select last_name
    , substr(first_name, 1, decode(instr(first_name,' -'), 0, length(first_name), instr(first_name,' -') -1)) as first_name
  from t1
;
```

Result:

```
LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME
--------- ----------
aaaa      bbb
aaa       bbbb
aaa       gggg j
```